# How could my lava plant work?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, xenobiology, mythical-creatures

Is it possible for a plant to live in the kind of environment that I created?
The environment has dim light, is underground, full of lava, and has constant lava explosions. This environment also has sentient pig people and giant boars. The plant is small, red, and has bulbs at the end of it's stalks. Water is almost non-existent along with absolutely no sunlight. Is this at all possible? How?

This is a short article that I made about the plant:

> **Stygius Calcaneumverucca**
>
> This plant, unlike its name, is not a mushroom.
>
> **The scientific name of your plant (genus+species)** Stygius Calcaneumverruca
>
> **What is the Classification of your plant? (Kingdom, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, Genus, Species)** Viridiplantae, Polypodiophyta,
> Polypodiopsida, Polypodiales, Pteridaceae, Stygius, Calcaneumverruca
>
> **What is the appearance of your plant?** Hell Shroom is a small fungus that grows on the sand in certain parts of a fiery dimension.
> Fully grown, they commonly reach heights of almost 36 inches or 3
> feet. The spores are rather large and are almost always at a size of
> 22 inches. The majority of the spore then roots into the ground
> showing a stem size, in its first stage of growth, of about 15 inches.
> In its second stage of growth, it reaches sizes of 27 inches. And its
> final and third stage of growth is, of course, 36 inches.
>
> **What are notable features of your plant?** Hell Shroom is also a fern because ferns are already highly adaptive to heat and light and
> they reproduce with spores, which Hell Shroom does. The colors are a
> dark red color. It grows on odd sand found in very hot parts of the
> universe. It is an extremely fast-growing plant taking a maximum of
> 13.653 hours to grow one stage and takes a maximum of 40.96 hours to grow to its third and final stage of growth. This fungus can only grow
> on the sand and can’t grow on soil. It is not affected much by
> environmental factors such as light and temperature.
>
> Lava produces carbon dioxide and Hell Shroom, being a plant, breathes
> in the CO2 and expels oxygen. The red color of the Hell Shroom was
> brought by the fact that pigs or piglins, which may eat them, cannot
> differentiate too much between shades of the same color. As Hell
> Shroom grows in fortresses, the bricks are a reddish-brown and the
> Hell Shrooms are a darkish red. They blend in with the surroundings
> from a pig person or a giant boar's point of view.
>
> Ferns have been known to live in caves with almost no light, this dimension does not provide almost any light. No plant needs absolutely no
> water, so the Hell Shroom synthesizes its own. It is extremely heat
> resistant, the growths at the end of the stems or stalks are where it
> combines hydrogen and part of the oxygen that it creates. But to get
> the hydrogen, it has another mechanism where it injects CO2 is
> injected it into an aqueous electrolyte, where reacts with a cathode,
> turning the solution more acidic, which in turn generates electricity
> and creates hydrogen. The spark that it creates is used to provide the
> activation energy necessary to combine the hydrogen and oxygen
> creating water. The water is absorbed by the plant to repeat this
> cycle. The cathode is made of purpurin which is a real-life natural
> dye found in plants. However, the cathode needs carbon to function at
> maximum capacity. The carbon is extracted from the ground using the
> roots.
>
> The roots of the Hell Shroom have few uses which are to anchor the
> plant firmly to the ground and extract carbon from the soil/sand.
> They also help insulate the plant from the heat emanating from the
> ground.
>
> It does not need light because the gene for getting energy via
> photosynthesis is instead with a gene encoding for a glucose
> transporter. It is found in real-world studies that algae and ferns
> altered with the gene for a human glucose transporter grew in dark
> fermenters at densities 15 times that of sunlight-grown algae. In
> addition, these tiny plants which are used in a number of dietary
> supplements were less likely to become contaminated.
>
> **Describe the main organs of the plant.** Roots, stem/stalk, and leaves/bulbs/growths.
>
> **Describe the life cycle.** The first stage through the third (last) stage all function the same. It is able to reproduce in any stage
> though it is most effective reproducing in its last stage. The spores
> stick to humans, or other creatures and then get planted.
>
> **Does it have a flower or not?** It does not have a flower. The growth on the end of the stem, in it’s final stage of growth, may or
> may not be considered a flower.
>
> **Does it reproduce with seeds or spores?**   It reproduces with spores. When a fully grown Hell Shroom is broken, they spread into 2-4
> Hell Shroom spores. An infantile Hell Shroom when broken, only spreads
> into 1 Hell Shroom spore. They rely on outside sources to spread.

Comment: It would be good to take the salient points from the linked document and include them in your question. Links can rot after all, and it would be nice if your question did not rot with them.

Comment: (1) An *"aqueous electrolyte"* is a solution of a salt in **water**. I don't get how the fungo-plant creates more water than in had initially. (2) Fungi are fungi, and plants are plants, and they are not the same. If \*\**Stygius calcaneumverucca* is a polypodiophyte then it is not a fungus. Fungi are more closely related to animals than to plants. Fungi and plants are very very different.

Comment: BTW, \*\**Stygius calcaneumverucca* is not an allowable scientific name, because it does not respect the basic rules. First, *stygius* is masculine and *...verruca* is feminine; the rule is that the name of the genus and the specific name must agree in grammatical gender. (And this gender is usually feminine for plants, but this is a soft rule.) Second, \*\**calcaneumverruca* is misformed as a Latin compound; try *verruca-calcanei* (e.g., real life *Arctostaphylos uva-ursi*) or *calciverruca*. (3) The genus name gets an upper case initial, the specific name starts with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Where does it get its energy to perform all the chemistry you've mentioned? They seem to be reactions which require the input of energy, so where does it come from?

Comment: This place looks a lot like The Nether, from Minecraft. Actually, you even called it "the nether" in the middle of your text.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's perfect. I know, it has a lot of flaws. Like, I didn't know about the scientific name.

Comment: A plant can't make all its own water chemically, making water requires energy and plants get energy by breaking down water. there is no way to get energy out if your systems for the plant to live or grow.

Comment: @AlexP gender is also a soft rule, the hard rules for nomenclature a few. Nomenclatures does not have to obey Latin grammar. Although you are correct about the letter cases. iapt-taxon.org/nomen/main.php

Comment: @John: It's a hard rule. If the specific name is an adjective then it *must* match the grammatical gender of the genus name; in this (and a very few other aspects) scientific names *must* obey Latin syntactic rules. See [article 23.5](https://www.iapt-taxon.org/nomen/pages/main/art_23.html): *"The specific epithet, when adjectival in form and not used as a noun, agrees with the gender of the generic name. [...] Epithets not conforming to this rule are to be corrected"*. Since \*\**calcaneumverucca* is misformed as a Latin compound I cannot tell whether it is to be an adjective or a noun.

Comment: @AlexP, learn something new every day, I guess I am too used ot animals where no one cares.

Comment: @John: Are you sure that no one cares? AFAIK, for example, *Lagopus \*\*mutus* was automatically renamed *Lagopus muta* when somebody realized that *lagopus* (Greek for "rabbit foot") was feminine. (But, yes, in general, scientific names are not necessarily Latin or Latinized Greek; this means that generic and specific names do not have to have meanings in Latin or Greek. The syntactic agreement rule kicks in when they *do* have a meaning in Latin or Greek.)

Comment: @AlexP for animals I am sure rhose rules are soft, individual authors may care, but so many new names are not using Latinized words that the rules for latin basically get ignored. Increasingly names may not even be published using ICZN rules but using phyloCode rules.  In paleontology it gets even weirder since names may change genus several times.

Answer (score 5):

Going through this scientifically point by point kind of feels like kicking a kitten but here goes.

- Lava does not make CO2.  It is not burning.  It is just hot rock.
- Plants can't synthesize the water they need and they need a fair bit because they strip off the hydrogen to make carbohydrate.
- Unless it is parasitic on a plant that gets light, a plant needs light to do photosynthesis (even cave dwelling ferns).  You could have a plant that ate glucose instead of making it.  That is what the parasitic plants do.  They are parasitic on something that makes glucose.
- Your plant gets hydrogen via some complicated electrical splitting of water of an electrolyte solution which is water.  Splitting water requires energy.  Plants use sunlight to do it.
- Fungi are not plants.  Most of this calls it a plant but it is also called a fungus.

Bio 101!

Plants get energy from the sun and use that energy to split water for the hydrogen.  The oxygen is waste.  They combine hydrogen with CO2 and make carbohydrate.  Animals eat the carbohydrate and produce the CO2 and H2O.

An ecosystem needs an energy source.  It can be light energy like the sunny top world.  It can be geochemical energy like deep ocean vents.  If you are digging it you can read a lot of ideas on this site about more exotic forms of energy that life might use, including heat, wind, electricity etc.

---

I do love creative minecraft things and I think the Nether is awesome especially with the recent update!  I feel bad about poking holes in your proffered science and I do not mean to insult you with my biochemistry primer.  Minecraft is not realistic (late breaking news!),  The total lack of water in the Nether means beings there must be going about biochemical things differently.  Water is needed for life as we know it.  I conclude Nether beings are supernatural weird beings.  You can have your weird nether fungus grow from the remains of dead supernatural beings.

Answer (score 0):

The carbon dioxide from the lava sounds helpful to the hell shroom, but it would need moisture to create nutrients and water probably is not exactly abundant in sand surrounded by lava. Nobody knows how Minecraft mushrooms grow, but it probably doesn't matter to most players.

Comment: Please see the requirements for the [tag:reality-check] tag.

Comment: Whilst an interesting aside, game mechanics don't directly answer the question. we invite you to take our [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work before posting. Enjoy the site.